# jQuery functions to Wordpress child theme using enqueue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

My wordpress knowledge is pretty low and I am in desperate need of help on adding some jQuery functions to a wordpress child theme.

I basically want to add [this effect](http://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/Animating-Numbers-Counting-Up-with-jQuery-Counter-Up-Plugin.html) to my `front-page.php`

I somewhat understand how to use the `functions.php` in order to enqueue my scripts.
Here is what my `functions.php` file looks like

```
 <?php
function enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'js name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/myfile.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
    wp_register_script( 'js name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/myfile.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
    wp_register_script( 'js name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/myfile.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );


    wp_enqueue_script( 'global' );

    if ( is_page( 'front-page' ) ) { // example page
        wp_enqueue_script( 'js name', 'js name', 'js name' );
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts' );
?>
```

As of right now it of course does not work.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your `js name`s shouldn't have a space in them. Also, no idea why you're registering the same script three times...

Comment: Give your enqueue_scripts function a unique name too. I'm assuming by not working you mean that the script calls don't show up in your source? And not just that the effect isn't working?

Comment: Sorry I should've made it a bit clearer, I'm not registering the same script. I have 3 scripts that all have different names with no spaces in the name. What I really don't get is how do I call the script in my front-page.php. This is the call for the script `<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
        $('.counter').counterUp({
            delay: 10,
            time: 1000
        });
    });
</script>`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function yourtheme_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'js_name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/myfile.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
    wp_register_script( 'js_name_2', get_template_directory_uri() . '/myfile2.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
    wp_register_script( 'js_name_3', get_template_directory_uri() . '/myfile3.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );


    if ( is_front_page() ) { 
        wp_enqueue_script( 'js_name' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'js_name_2' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'js_name_3' );
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'yourtheme_enqueue_scripts' );
```

In your themes root folder (same folder as functions.php), create new file called *myfile.js*. This is the file you refer to in the function above.

As you theme grows in size, it's better to organise your files. You can do this by creating subfolders, like this:

- Create a folder named assets (name could be anything);
- Inside assets create three new folders called js, css and images;
- Put your files in the right folders;
- Update your function to follow the right path to your folders;

e.g.

```
wp_register_script( 'js_name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/myfile.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
```

Note: You don't have to close `?>` in your functions.php.

Comment: Thanks! How do I trigger the script from my front-page.php? This is the part where I'm most confused about. Where and how do I add this: `<script> jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) { $('.counter').counterUp({ delay: 10, time: 1000 }); }); </script>`

Comment: In your themes root folder, make a file called myfile.js and add your jQeury to it without the script tags.

Comment: So do I also have to list myfile.js to the functions.php list?

Comment: You have to do both, see my updated answer. Do you have `<?php wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); ?>` right before `<?php wp_head(); ?>` in your themes header?

Comment: Tim thanks for all the help. I'm still having trouble with this. Is the js code supposed to start with `jQuery(document).ready` or can it start directly with just `(function( $ ){`  ? I have combined the 2 js files into one to make it more simple for me and here is how my code starts. This is working outside of wordpress....   `(function( $ ){
  "use strict";

  $.fn.counterUp = function( options ) {`  I can only show you the beginning because it's too long to post here.

Comment: I only now realize that you are trying to use a jQuery plugin. Did you include the plugin's jQuery file in the theme?

Comment: I have in my js folder. I'm working on a child theme so I have my child theme folder which includes a js folder with the plugin jquery file. I also created a functions.php (outside of the js folder) file to enqueue the jquery file in. I wish there was a better way to show you what's going on.

Comment: Do not combine the two files, it's easier for me to see where it's going wrong if the files are separate. Update your post with the steps you've taken so far. Do you work from a live website or locally?